# What is the term for the person leaving the position and person replacing the position in a secondment

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, north-american-english

In academia, professors will sometimes *take a secondment* where they take a break from their normal role and someone will temporarily replace them.

I am uncertain about the correct words for this process.  I think this is correct, but I am unsure.

- The person leaving their position is called: **The secondee**
- The person leaving their position is taking: **A secondment**
- A person who is away from their position is: **On secondment**
- The person replacing the secondee temporarily is: **?**

Comment: Professors take a "sabbatical" or they take "leave" from their professorial positions. They don't take a "secondment" unless they are temporarily assigned to another faculty or to another institution where they will continue to work for a period of time until recalled. The word "secondment" is more commonly used in the British military where a soldier, sailor or airman is transferred on "loan" from his position and role to another branch of the military. British military personnel in WWll were often seconded (pronounced seh-con-did) to their American allies as liaison officers.

Comment: In Australia, the person replacing a secondee would typically be called the *replacement*, the *locum*, the *temp* or the *backfill* depending on the nature of the secondee's vacated position and the industry. But since you've asked for a US or North American usage, I won't offer a formal answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gleaned my answers about secondments from [this document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiO6dfq_6_PAhUN4GMKHWHnDJgQFghEMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fadmin.1fife.org.uk%2Fuploadfiles%2Fpublications%2Fc64_TE12_Secondment_Guidelines.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGrv76NPmQnM4DBnIoPRYpsV5ZCaQ) from the Fife Council in Scotland and [this UK job board](http://www.jobs.ac.uk/careers-advice/careers-advice/593/going-on-secondment):

- A person leaving their *substantive* (primary) position is the *secondee*
- A person leaving their substantive position is taking a *secondment*
- A person who is away from their substantive position is *on secondment*
- A person who is *covering* the secondee's substantive role temporarily may themselves be a secondee, or simply a temporary employee

Comment: Quite so! However, the OP informs us that the professor in question is taking a "break from [his] normal role". This suggests a sabbatical which usually involves a term or semester's absence while on study or research leave. A "break" might also connote some kind of rest or holiday from his role. I just wonder if secondment to another position is compatible with a "break from [his] normal role" as per the OP?

Comment: @PeterPoint it appears that many academic institutions in the UK make a distinction between *sabbatical* and *secondment*, the latter typically referring to temporarily taking on a different full-time (paid) position (usually at a different institution, though I think it could also mean in a different branch of the same organization, especially in industry as opposed to academia). It's not a term I've heard commonly in US academia, though.